# Unknown AWS S3 Get and Put Requests in my account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get

I am new to using AWS s3. I was experimenting with static website hosting and other things using s3. This was like 3 months back. I deleted all the public buckets 2 months ago, and I have only 2 buckets left, and they are not public, and I have no services running. But still, I have this weird Get and put requests to my s3. I can't find out the reason.

[Billing for S3][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VGlZ.png

I'm hesitant to use cloudwatch since its logs are again stored in s3 and the no. of put request will change.

Comment: Are you referring to the 5871 GET (and other) requests for $0.00 and 3212 PUT/COPY/POST/LIST requests for $0.02? Do you ever use the S3 management console or put/get objects into your existing buckets? They would contribute towards those API calls. Also, any services that store data in S3 would trigger API requests (eg CloudFormation, which stores stack templates in S3).

Comment: No i am not actively using the s3 console. I didn't add any files or read files from any buckets from the starting of the month.